# how find minimal distances

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have a vector like which represents 8 distances:

```
distance=[6.5 2.5 6.2 3.01 4.7 4.03 5.09 5.09];
```

I would like to keep only the 2 minimal distances of this vector.

For this I use

```
[sort_dist index] = sort(distance);
Two_minimal_distance = sort_dist(1:2);
```

But to find indexes of the 2 minimal distances without sort the vector ?

Comment: Why without sorting? Also, what if `2.5` is repeated several times? Do you want indices of `unique` elements, or with repetitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows.  The result is the 1×2 vector `ind`.

- If you want the indices of the two smallest entries **even if they have the same value**:

  ```
  distance=[6.5 2.5 6.2 3.01 4.7 4.03 5.09 5.09]; % data
  tmp = distance; % copy of data. Will be overwritten
  [~, ind] = min(tmp); % index of minimum value
  tmp(ind) = NaN; % overwrite with NaN, so the subsequent call to min will ignore it
  [~, ind(2)] = min(tmp); % index of second-minimum value
  ```
- If you want the indices of the (first occurrence of the) two smallest **unique** values:

  ```
  distance=[6.5 2.5 6.2 3.01 4.7 4.03 5.09 5.09]; % data
  tmp = distance; % copy of data. Will be overwritten
  [val, ind] = min(tmp); % value and index of minimum value
  tmp(tmp==val) = NaN; % overwrite all occurrences of that value
  [~, ind(2)] = min(tmp); % index of second-minimum unique value
  ```

Comment: for the second case you can also do `[~, ind(2)] = min(distance(distance~=min(distance))` so you don't need aux variable since you don't need to overwrite the occurrences.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Good point. I'll leave it as it is though, because of similarity with the first case